# Understanding CPU fan ref design

Tags: mosfet, fan

I'm currently designing a carrier board for the Jetson Orin NX 16GB SoM (system on module).

I'm having trouble understanding the ref design of the fan management part. The part about fan management is page 74-75 of the [design guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/downloads/jetson-orin-nx-series-nano-series-design-guide). There don't seem to be much useful information excepted the bellow schematics:
[image: Schematics]

For the fan header, pin 1 is ground, pin 2 is Vcc (5V), pin 2 is tachometer (I suppose open drain, but not sure), pin 4 is PWM.

The bottom part (between pin 230 of Jetson to fan header pin 4) is, if I'm not mistaken, simply a level shifter from 1.8 V (Jetson GPIO voltage) to 5 V. Correct? Is there any reason to use 5 discrete components rather than an all integrated level shifter?

For the middle part (between pin 208 of Jetson and pin 3 of fan header (tachymeter signal from fan), it seems to be shifting down from 5 to 1.8 V, maybe with pulling up if the tachymeter is open drain. Is there a reason why not just to use a voltage divider for the down shifting?

And my main interrogation is the supply part (between VDD_5V_IN at the top and pin 2 of fan header):

- I think there is an error on the MOSFET with reference SM2309 (ie the top most). I couldn't find a decent datasheet. I have one for the [SM2309PSA](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1137565/SINOPWER/SM2309PSA.html) from some obscure manufacturer, and one for the [TSM2309](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/395/TSM2309_A15-1116136.pdf) that seems to be a decent part (referenced on Mouser). In both cases, it's a P-MOS (but they are not the same). I would also guess a P-MOS would make more sense than the N-MOS drawn (there seems to be no easy way to get a V_GS>0)
- If indeed this MOSFET should be a PMOS, how should it be wired? And what function (protection) does it provide?
- Any idea why they add the 100 µH inductor? (the diodes are for free wheeling)

So my main question is if SM2309 should be a P-MOS instead, and if so how it should be wired and why?

For the other parts, I have a feeling it might be over-complicated, but not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So my main question is if SM2309 should be a P-MOS instead, and if so
> how it should be wired and why?*

It certainly looks like it should be a p-channel MOSFET because an n-channel MOSFET will just behave like a forward-biased diode as it is shown in your question. I strongly suspect it is an attempt to produce a reverse voltage polarity protection circuit like this: -

[image]

Image from [Reverse polarity protection with a P-MOSFET](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2017/08/19/reverse-polarity-protection-with-a-p-mosfet/).

> *Any idea why they add the 100µH inductor? (the diodes are for free
> wheeling)*

It looks like it will keep fan electrical noise from appearing on the main 5 volt supply i.e. it's a filter and, as you say, the diodes are there to catch the flyback energy from the inductor to prevent excessive back emf.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Do you have any idea why they would put a reverse polarity protection? From what I understand it is to protect the fan when if we put -5V on the VDD_5V_IN. But the VDD_5V_IN is the main supply of the Jetson that costs hundreds of dollars (and it would be fried as well), so protecting the fan seems useless. Or is it somehow protecting the Jetson from the fan?

Comment: @Sandro I have no idea why it will be needed just as I have no idea why they drew it like they did originally.

Comment: @Sandro are we done here or do you have further comments to make? I'm sorry I can't answer your supplemental questions in your previous comment but, if they got the MOSFET wrong (as I suspect) then, it's likely that they just cobbled together a reverse polarity circuit because someone may have thought it was a good idea (design by committee etc.).

Comment: If nobody has a another guess, then your answer is probably the right one (I'm just waiting to see if anyone comes up with a better explanation of why they added this MOSFET, other than "for no good reason")

Comment: If I haven't gotten any other explanation yet, I suppose I won't get any.

Answer (score 0):

The fan becomes like a 2 watt generator on power down so the FET acts an isolation switch and the transient energy is dumped inside the fan.

The other circuits are level shifters to protect a low voltage CPU or uC.

Added

Yes you are correct or at least I agree, the 5Vin uses a PMOS switch shown incorrectly as an NMOS. Send a note to NVidia for the correction if they do not already know. At least the base part number is good enough to confirm.  It’s a common oversight and why we have revisions to documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you please elaborate : for the protection as you think, should it be a NMOS (as drawn) or a PMOS (as idicated by the reference)? Connected how (if it's a PMOS)? Protecting against what exactly? Positive voltage on the fan header? Above 5V? Or Above 0 while 5V is off? Or negative voltage?